Intention delaying Salah
I deliberately delayed Fajr Salah for years, not knowing it wouldn’t  invalidate  prayers, I then reliazed that they invalid Salah then I acted as like i overslept without having a alarm. I repented and now question if I  should redo those delayed prayers.Im in severe depression someone help.
